# How to serve a subdirectory react app with node js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, create-react-app, package.json

I have a react application that I want to deploy to a subdirectory so I've set the homepage attribute in package.json file to my subdirectory name ("homepage": "/dashboard/"), and some other things as said in this link:

https://medium.com/@svinkle/how-to-deploy-a-react-app-to-a-subdirectory-f694d46427c1

I am serving my app with a server.js file using nodejs.

The problem I'm having is that when i set the homepage attribute and build the app when I run my server.js file i'm getting the noscript error: "You need to enable JavaScript to run this app" in my browser.

Am I missing something? Should I do something to my server.js file as well?

Comment: this link helped me fix my issue: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/1812